# How can I make Kendo UI Panelbar "skip" an element when reading an HTML list?

Tags: html, knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

I'm using Knockout.js 3.3 and utilizing components with custom elements. I am trying to use Kendo UI's `Panelbar` with that list. The only problem is, it fails (the nested `<ul>` won't expand) because my lists are in the following format:

```
<ul>
    <sidebar-step>
        <li>some message
            <ul>
                <li>some sub message<li>
                <li>another sub message</li>
            <ul>
        </li>
    </sidebar-step>
</ul>
```

`<sidebar-step>` is a custom element that contains a template for `<li>` and a sublist. I'm guessing since `<sidebar-step>` is not a usual sub-element of `<ul>`, it is causing it to mess up.

Is there a way to make Kendo UI somehow "ignore" the `<sidebar-step>` tag?

**Edit**: if it's not possible, what can I do to make the list expandable (even with this custom element)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [component binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html) on the outer `<li>` rather than creating a custom tag.

A minimal example:

```
<ul>
    <li data-bind="component:'sublist'"></li>
</ul>
```

Script:

```
ko.components.register('sublist', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        this.text = 'something';
        this.subtext = ['one','two'];
    },
    template: '<!-- ko text:text --><!-- /ko --><ul data-bind="foreach:subtext"><li data-bind="text:$data"></li></ul>'
});

ko.applyBindings();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lohfscdg/

Comment: Thanks... you have answered all 4 of my Knockout.js questions lol

Comment: I aspire to be the dominant force in Knockout question-answering.

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing? I'm having trouble converting my `<sidebar-step>` elements into `<li>` elements. Ignore the sub-list part for this. I'm not really sure how to do it since my format is a bit different from your fiddle. Can you help me convert them? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mpqtsjhL/1/

Comment: I feel I am close with this: http://jsfiddle.net/mpqtsjhL/8/ but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong exactly

Comment: The component template should include all the tags that go inside it. Params are processed by the viewmodel constructor. This is more like what you were trying for. http://jsfiddle.net/mpqtsjhL/9/